# From array to priority queue

Tags: c++, arrays, priority-queue

I have items in array created from this struct:

```
struct ks{
    int cap;
    int val;
};
```

Array is named **items** and contains **quantity** of items.

```
items = new ks[quantity];
```

I want to put them in priority queue - which basically means sort them.

This is my compare function:

```
struct itemsCompare{
    bool operator () (const ks &item1, const ks &item2){
        if (item1.val/item1.cap > item2.val/item2.cap) return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

How should creating of this queue looks like?

```
priority_queue <ks, What should I put here?, itemsCompare> comparedItems;
for(int i=0; i<quantity; i++) comparedItems.push(items[i]);
```

I know, that template requires having vector as container. How should I modify code to make it work? I know that I can put items into vector just before declaration of priority queue, but I'm curious if there's a way to do it just with array.

Comment: Put `std::vector<ks>` there.

Comment: Also please make a *small, simple* program that evaluates division expressions like you propose and make sure they behave as you want them to.

Comment: And make the function call operator overload `const`.

Comment: When comparing quotients of integers, it's better to rearrange the (in)equation to compare products by cross-multiplying the (in)equation. `item1.val * item2.cap > item2.val * item1.cap` This way you avoid integer division rounding errors your code probably suffers from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question as asked:

```
std::priority_queue <ks, std::vector<ks>, itemsCompare> comparedItems;
```

However, the question has some issues not directly asked. First, it sports division on uncontrolled substances :). What is going to happen if you divide by 0?

Second. You divide integer by integer. This result is always integer, and somehow I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: After building code I get some strange errors, like 'undefined reference to ' and there's my compare function. Something is wrong with this compare.

Comment: **/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/bits/predefined_ops.h:144: error: undefined reference to `branchandbound::itemsCompare::operator()(branchandbound::ks const&, branchandbound::ks const&)'** - branchandbound is my class

Comment: Okay... I know where I had problem. I simply wrote whole compare struct into my class's header file and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

To create a [`std::priorty_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) from the array you can use

```
std::priority_queue <ks, std::vector<ks>, itemsCompare> comparedItems(items, items + quantity);
```